# In JIRA, how can I show certain columns to specific users?

Tags: scrum, agile, sprint, backlog, jira

Let's say I have five columns in my project. They are visible in a Scrum project when a sprint begins, as expected, when you click on the "Work" tab in the Plan / Work / Report options.

One || Two || Three || Four || Five

What I'd like is for one user or group of users to see the following when they click "Work".

- One
- Two
- Three

And then I'd like another user or group of users to see the following when they click "Work".

- Three
- Four
- Five

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

That's not available as a direct feature for a single board that you can enforce as the board creater/owner, however, you can easily [Copy an Existing Board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Creating+a+Board#CreatingaBoard-CopyinganExistingBoard), then [Configure the Columns](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Columns) in each one as desired and make the board available to the resp. target audience.

- Please note that the *ability to access JIRA Agile Scrum board is controlled by the **filter that is currently in use by that board***. So if this isn't only about usability, rather also about security, you would need to also adjust the [filter](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Filters) in use, see [How to restrict the access to JIRA Agile Scrum board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/How+to+restrict+the+access+to+JIRA+Agile+Scrum+board).